# Why did I fail this review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality

I was doing a Late Answers run when i came across [this review](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/985976) which was an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/633026/most-keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-in-word-2010-on-windows-8)

> go to windows setting -language -add language look if the language is different than the keyboard change it to us

It doesn't look like a *great* answer, but it does ostensibly try to answer the question. Why was this answer deleted, and why did I fail the audit?

Comment: You failed the audit due to the fact the answer had already been deleted and you indicated the answer was acceptable quality.  If it had been deleted that cannot be the case.  The answer was extremely low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be improved quite a bit. The formatting could be changed to a list. Proper punctuation could be added. Proper capitalization could be added.

That's an example of a low-quality answer.

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the question. Broken shortcut keys in word have nothing to do do with language settings. Note this is a pretty poor question with a bunch of poor answers.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't read the question, just the answer that was reviewed; my bad.

Comment: That's exactly why people fail review audits. Always check the original post if in doubt :)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's what I was looking for (it wasn't obvious what was wrong)